# How to Add expiry header on thirdparty JS and CSS file in WordPress

Tags: htaccess

I am using different plugins in WordPress like Disqus comment system, Theia Post slider and other.. Here is a result from GTmatrix :

[image: Result from gtmetrix.com]

I want to know how can I add expiry header on third party JS files and CSS files. I want to increase my Y-Slow grade.

Comment: Better look at your requests, 128 is ridiculous. That should not be more that 50 which is already going to the high side

Comment: You can't add expiry header on thirdparty JS and CSS file unless you host them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert mentioned in comments, you can't add any additional headers (`Expires`, `Cache-Control`, etc.) to any resources (JS, CSS, images, etc.) that are hosted and served by a third party, unless you have direct control of that third party in order to do so. Perhaps if the third party offers this as a feature.

You can only add additional HTTP response headers to resources that you are directly serving from your site.

However, there is a "theoretical workaround". You can potentially configure part of your site as a *proxy* (or temporary store for these external resources). For example, the links to these third party files are changed to point to your site. Your server then makes a "proxy" request to the third party resource which is sent back to your server and your server then sends this back to the client, with any additional HTTP response headers (eg. `Expires`) you might want to set. However, this is non-trivial, a potential security hole if done incorrectly and may not be possible anyway if the entire tool is hosted externally, as is the case with Disqus.